# how to auto run script when users chan change to specified directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to users auto a sshfs mount when they change to specified directory.
alias may do the trick , but it's diffuclt to configure alias for all users with different mount requests.

What I think is something like this

```
cd ~/abc will auto run sshfs abc@abc.com:/home/abc
```

and not only in shell , but also in nautilus or other file manage applications.

is there any way to do so ?

Comment: I think you want [AutoFS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-autofs), also known as the automounter.

Comment: thanks for the hint , I will lean AutoFS ASAP , !